# Why is this angular binding not working?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="person" [(ngModel)]="person.selected" />
```

This is shown on a `ngFor` loop. I output the `selected` value for testing purposes and some are true and some other are false, despite of this, ALL checkboxes are checked.

Is there anything wrong on the binding syntax?

Comment: You need to show more code and what's going on in your .ts file.  The syntax looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the same `name` on all checkboxes. Using unique names did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue using the binding, make sure `selected` is truthy or falsy.

```
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
     <h1 class="title">Simple component</h1>
      <div *ngFor="let person of persons" >
         {{person.name}}
         <input type="checkbox" name="person" [(ngModel)]="person.selected" />
      </div>
    `
    })
    export class AppComponent {

    persons = [
     {
      name: "first",
      selected: true
     },
     {
      name: "second",
      selected: false
     },
     {
      name: "third",
      selected: false
     },
     {
      name: "fourtch",
      selected: true
     }
    ]
  }
```

Here is [Plunker!](http://plnkr.co/edit/ij3QGb?p=preview)